# Do I Still Need to Insert Analytics Code after HTML File Verification

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

After verifying my domain through HTML file verification should I also insert analytics code into Yoast SEO plugin or within functions.php file? Similarly, Is it safe to delete the html file after the verification?

Thanks,

Tahir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here but it sounds like you are confusing Google Webmaster Tools and Google Analytics.

I which case you'll have to keep the html file AND you have to insert Google Analytics code.

Google Webmaster Tools give you information about what people see in the search result list and if your site gets crawled correctly by Google. Google Analytics tell you where your visitors come from and what they do on your site, so these are quite different things.

Plus this probably belongs to webmasters.stackexchange.com (it's not exactly a programming question).

Comment: Thanks a lot Eike, so should I add the Analytics code to Yoast SEO plugin or into Funcations.php file?

Comment: Should I use Yoast's Google Analytics plugin to do those tasks & avoiding messing up with code?

Comment: Yes, it's best to insert Google Analytics via a separate plugin (I don't use the GA plugin by Yoast so I can't say anything about it but their stuff is usually fine - so you should be good with Yoast).